# May I have multiple root files in Latex VSCode project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Is it possible to have a single VSCode workspace and have multiple root tex files inside so that I can have multiple output pdfs?

I have to prepare an application where I need to submit a CV, a motivation letter, and a 2-year plan. Can I manage this in a single VSCode workspace?